# Only my service foreground is awake, not the managers member of the service

Tags: java, android, kotlin, service

I have a service that refers to a MainManager who is referring to other managers including a blamanager (all managers are singleton).

The BLE communcation must continue when the application is Killed.

That's why I created a service foreground that remains awake even when the application is Killed, but only the hand service remains awake and not the managers who depend on it.

Why? All managers need to be services? Or how to make the service dependent managers continues to work even when the app is killed?

You can see below the architecture:
[image]

What is the solution to my problem? If I have to turn my managers into services, it will break my architecture (I hope this is not the solution..), so what are my solutions?

Comment: If your "manager" is not an Android service, what do you then mean when you say it's not "awake"? What is a "manager"? A class? An object? A separate process?

Comment: When android killed your app he disconnected ble device. Even if android restart your app with foreground service you should start all your services again (it should be at Application's onCreate or foreground service onCreate/onStartCommand )?